# Showing an inequality with $\lim \inf$ and integrals of continuous postive function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, inequality

Suppose that we have a continuous function $f:[0,\infty[\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ then I would like to see that

> $\lim \inf_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{T}\log \int_{0}^{T}f(x)dx\geq \lim \inf_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{T}\log f(T)$

Now my idea was to take a sequence $t_n\rightarrow \infty$ such that $\lim \inf_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{T}\log \int_{0}^{T}f(x)dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{t_n}\log \int_{0}^{t_n}f(x)dx$ and then try something as $\lim \inf_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{T}\log f(T) \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{t_n}\log f(t_n)$ and now I would like to have something like $f(t_n)\leq A\int_{0}^{t_n}f(x)dx$ for some $A>0$. Is this possible or is there another way to prove this ? Thanks in advance.

An idea I had was to use the mean value theorem for integrals on each $[0,t_n]$, that is we know that there exists $c_n>0$ such that $\int_{0}^{t_n}f(x)dx=f(c_n)t_n$.

But then to have what I want I need to use the the fac that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{t_n}\log(f(t_n))=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{t_n}\log(f(c_n))$ and I have no idea if this is true .

Does anyone know if this is true or if there is another of how to prove this ? Thanks in advance.